# Can I use "from importlib import abc" on python2.7

Tags: python-importlib

I can use `from importlib import abc` and `from importlib import util` normally on Python 3. However, when I have to run the same code on Python 2.7, I got `ImportError`.

I found that `importlib2` seems to be able to solve this problem, but when I installed this package (version 3.5.0.2) and tried to use it, the command `import importlib2` gave me an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\importlib2_*init*_.py", line 23, in 
> _bootstrap._setup(sys, *imp)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\importlib2_fixers_*init**.py", line 348, in _setup
> setup(sys_module, _imp_module)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\importlib2_bootstrap.py", line 2492, in _setup
> os_module = _builtin_from_name(builtin_os)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\importlib2_bootstrap.py", line 2431, in _builtin_from_name
> raise NotImplementedError
> NotImplementedError

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: importlib2 was never developed to the point of a stable release, and has not been maintained since 2014. (Python 2 itself has not been maintained since 2020.)

Comment: *Why* are you trying to execute `from importlib import abc`, anyway? `importlib.abc` doesn't exist on Python 2, and it's only useful in combination with other parts of the `importlib` system that don't exist on Python 2 either. The entire import system has been overhauled since Python 2.

Comment: @user2357112 I need to make my code compatible with Python 2. It seems that I cannot use importlib.abc and importlib.util on Python 2. Do I need to re-write another code specifically for Python 2?

Comment: Probably, or it might even be the case that the fundamental purpose of your code doesn't make sense on Python 2 at all, no matter how you rewrite it.